# Content Types how to use them

Tags: content-type, custom-list

I essentially want to put two forms into 1 list, some of the items they contain are the same and some are different.
I'm not really sure how content types work. I essentially want first for the user to select either Veg or Meat, which will take them onto a form depending on what they selected.
I've done a bit of research and believe having two base content types is the best way forward.
Just need some explanation on how to go about this, I am using sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you must use content type for this case!
Go to Site Setting and site content type then Create 2 content type for each them and create them columns!
So create a list and go to list setting and Advance setting so Choice
Allow management of content types? **Yes**.
Add from existing site content types then add your content type.
Then Go to form setting and then you can customize your new content types form.

I hope that this is usefull!!!

Comment: Hey aMir, You might would like to add why you think "Yes you must use content type for this case! ", to get my up-vote :)